# Отключить кэш на всех поддоменах в cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare

Сайт использует cloudflare. На основном домене example.com включен кэш cloudflare. Но есть с десяток поддоменов, на которых я не хочу использовать кэш cloudflare. Сейчас для одного поддомена настроено правило `*sub1.example.com/* Cache Level: Bypass.` Это правило отлично работает. Но как мне применить данное правило сразу для всех поддоменов, чтобы при этом основной домен example.com по-прежнему кэшировался?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете отключить проксирование поддоменов через Cloudflare в настройках DNS или отдавать с вашего бэкенда заголовок ответа `Cloudflare-CDN-Cache-Control:no-store`.